# Auto populate a select field from choosing the product on the previous page

Tags: php, html, forms, drop-down-menu

I have a site with a product menu which then goes through to a quote page (all products share same quote page)

I have a select box with all the products inside (what product are you interested in?) and want to populate the answer from the product page the visitor has clicked on - what is the simplest way to do this please?

Comment: Show us some of the relevant code, like the html for the textfields, and anything you've treie so far. Are you using cookies or session variables?

Comment: Update! Thanks Depperm but I have now resolved with the code below:
http://pastebin.com/kxc060Y4

Answer (score 0):

Resolved with Session Variables
http://pastebin.com/kxc060Y4